# Vagrant "Cannot Stat 000" Error

Tags: bash, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm on Windows 7, I have a vagrant provision bash file for ubuntu 14.04 that looks like so:

```
echo "copying in nginx conf and files";
mv ~/static/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf;
mv ~/static/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/;
```

The output of `vagrant provision` is:

```
==> default: copying in nginx conf and files
==> default: mv:
==> default: cannot stat ���/root/static/nginx.conf���
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: mv:
==> default: cannot stat ���/root/static/default���
==> default: : No such file or directory
```

Whats with the weird "nully" codes, why doesnt my move command work?

Comment: do you have that file in your guest computer? `/root/static/nginx.conf` how it comes here?

Comment: yep, its in there. i feel like the issue is the nully things?

Comment: I Don't think so. My guess is that you are running a script that was written with a windows editor (eg notepad) so it has incorrect End Of Line (EOL) characters for linux.

Comment: It looks like something is trying to print the file names with quotation marks, but it's using `“”` rather than `""`, and they aren't rendering correctly (perhaps a UTF-8 vs. UTF-16 vs. Windows-1252 problem). For example, `“` is U+201C, which is represented as 3 bytes in UTF-8; if the output device isn't expecting UTF-8 that's the kind of think you're likely to see. I think there are two distinct problems here: displaying the quotation marks incorrectly, and using an incorrect file name. (Does `/root/static/nginx.conf` exist?)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your script is using Windows newlines instead of Unix. Convert them to Unix. If using vi, the command is ":set ff=unix" or use dos2unix

Comment: oops, sure, you absolutelly right. `dos2unix`, fixed, my fault

Comment: i did this with sublime, but wouldn't the newlines manifest themselves with `\r` errors, not this one?

Comment: look, unix uses LF as end of the line, windows CR+LF, so try to open this file in unix machine, if you will see some additional symbols so you uses wrong filetype.

Comment: I don't think a line ending problem would cause the reported symptom.

Comment: Or maybe it could; there might be a CR at the end of the file name.

Comment: In any way dosen't matter it is encoding or filetype problem, to avoid it Micah have to open this file in some unix editor and look on them by eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting the file to end up in `/home/vagrant` when in actuality it was being copied to `/root`.

So the lesson here is that while you ssh in as the vagrant user the provision is ran as root.